# Why asterisk server updates the status of clients after one minute

Tags: voip, asterisk, pbx

Can any body please tell me that when i unregistered my soft phone (xlite) client, i execute "sip show peers" command on asterisk server then why it shows its status (OK) .
When i execute same command after a minute then it shows (UNKNOWN) status.
It actually updates the status after a minute ? why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While creating sip account in sip.conf add following attributes.

```
[211]
.
.
.
qualify=yes
qualifyfreq=3 (time in seconds in which sip status will be updated)
```

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk%20sip%20qualify

Comment: This idea is very bad. As result asterisk will send packet every 3 seconds, for most device it can take upto 3 seond to respond on it. IF you have more then 10 device you will have real issues with perfomance and you WILL have your device flapping.

Comment: what if i have a server with 32 GB RAM ??? may be there is another simple solution is that when we execute  "sip show peer 215 (extension number) " it displays various attributes in including "Status" and "Addr->IP"...So it is better to monitor only "Addr->IP" attribute because it rapidly changes to null when any sip client unregistered, whereas "Status" is updated after one minute....what is your opinion ??

Comment: quality is ok, just set it to 10 or more. 32gb ram will give you nothing. asterisk very rare use more then 2gb.

Answer (score 1):

You xlite work not correctly,and not do any unregister action. Status become unknown when xlite not do re-registration in next re-register interval.

You can decrease time by moving out from xlite(very buggy software) to other softphone or by decreasing registration time to 20-30 sec.

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply.I have also tested it on Yealink sip t22p (hardphone) and face the same problem. I installed Asterisk with the same version (1.6.2.11) on different virtual machine and finds that it is working perfectly, it updates the status rapidly as client unregisters. I dont know why it updates the status after one minute in my old asterisk virtual machine (in which mysql, Apache, Apache tomcat, eclipse is also installed). ??

Comment: I am sorry, you have debug issues yourself, becuase it not comnifrmed by other. I recomend you try decrease registration interval.

Comment: Thanks for your support arheops.  I have solved the problem and answered my own question.....